# How to group by and order by in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table with data as follow, I want to select data follow group by and order by as picture bellow

```
SELECT  USER_ID, USER_PROFILE_ID, START_DATE FROM ABC
    ORDER BY START_DATE DESC
```

[image]

As result , i have 3 rows, Now , i want to 2 rows, I'll ORDER BY START_DATE and delete same rows GROUP BY USER_ID and USER_PROFILE_ID

Comment: What is the meaning of the orange rectangle in the image?

Comment: Can you explain what grouping you're trying to achieve? It's not clear from the attached image.

Comment: Ah, as result , i have 3 rows, Now , i want to 2 rows, I'll sort by START_DATE and delete same rows

Comment: ok, i add more detail in picture , please see it .

Comment: So, you want all unique `USER_ID` and `USER_PROFILE_ID` values and the maximum `START_DATE` value for each?

Comment: Yes, example , you can see 2 rows with USER_ID and USER_PROFILE_ID same , I'll select row with value of START_DATE max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the most recent row (for a given user & profile) use:

```
SELECT  
    USER_ID, 
    USER_PROFILE_ID, 
    MAX(START_DATE) as START_DATE  
FROM ABC
GROUP BY USER_ID, USER_PROFILE_ID
```

You could add an ORDER BY to this. Note to order by date you would need to use MAX(START_DATE) DESC.

More details at the SQL documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx